# What typical processes does the Software Engineering discipline consist of?

Tags: terminology, development-process

I'm reading the "Guide to software engineering body of knowledge" but I am very confused.

Does a typical process consist of: implementation and change, definition, assessment, process and product measurement?

Or does it consist of Software requirements, design, construction, testing and maintenance? I thought this was the answer to my question but I'm starting to have doubts

Comment: Hah! “Typical” the discipline is far too immature for that.

Comment: you are new in this forum, please make always a concrete question so you dont receive dislikes. And for all who give dislikes without comment, its also recommended to be nice :D give hints how to improve the question, so he can formulate a better one.

Comment: @Khan: part of the community here is pretty resistant against commenting their downvotes, see [my meta post from 2019](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8884/can-we-improve-our-style-of-self-moderation-for-not-too-bad-questions) - though it got 36 upvotes, it got also 5 downvotes, most probably from the same community members who regularly downvote every second question wihout commenting.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_engineering) has a definition of the fields which does not look too wrong, and uses more or less your second list of terms. The only difference I can spot is the term "development" instead of "construction".

But I don't think your first list is different - these are terms with almost the same meaning.

For software, "implementation" can mean "design" and "construction"; "change" can mean "maintenance", assessment can also mean "testing", and "process and product measurement" can be seen as part of "Software development". So both of your definitions are applicable.

Since you asked about "a typical process" - Software Engineering is a larger discipline, not a "process" in the narrow sense of something where you simply follow a list of fixed steps one-by-one to reach a certain goal (like developing a new app). If that is what you are looking for, you better start changing your expectations.

---

<sub>**Note:** Here on the Software Engineering site we focus on the [Systems Development life Cycle (SDLC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_development_life_cycle), except for the coding part. We exclude the latter not because it does not belong to the field of software engineering, but because for coding questions there is a better and more specialized site: Stackoverflow.com.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Software Engineering *from Who's perspective?*

To me software engineering is pretty simple: **Person/Organisation has a problem. Solve it.**

That entails a lot of possible outcomes:

- maybe its not a problem,
- maybe its something simple like getting the right people talking,
- maybe you have to actually do something to the software.

The sparkly words in between are an attempt to describe the process called *Learning*.

Learning is what you do to figure out:

- the problem,
- what might solve it,
- and if it has been solved.

Comment: This definition also fits to engineers, managers, mathematicians, moderators and janitors.

Comment: Indeed it does.

Comment: The software part is simply the mechanism for the solution. Not implying its trivial, just pointing out that engineering is engineering even if its the janitor's work on a better system for cleaning. And engineering is about learning how to solve a problem with what you know, in a good/better way.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a "typical process". The closest thing that you would find would be sets of activities, such as in a definition of a software development life cycle, [systems development life cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_development_life_cycle), or [product development life cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_lifecycle). [ISO/IEC/IEEE 12207 Systems and software engineering – Software life cycle processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_12207) attempts to define a standard definition of processes or activities found across software development - not all of the activities described are necessary to build software. Still, they include those commonly needed or found in teams and organizations of various sizes.

Unfortunately, there aren't any universal, or even widely, accepted ways to break down the activities. ISO/IEC/IEEE 12207 is probably the closest you'd find. Guide to the SWEBOK probably isn't the best breakdown, since it's not meant to organize activities and processes but the set of knowledge that is key to the discipline of software engineering - several of the knowledge areas relate to processes and activities, but that's not the intent of the document.

Answer (score 1):

If we were being perfectly honest with ourselves, software development doesn't consist much of typical processes at all.

Overarching descriptions of process, if they are not obviously inconsistent with reality, are typically so abstract as to be almost meaningless - they are scarcely any more specific than saying development consists of "thinking and typing", for all it helps the *uninitiated* understand what is really going on.

There is often an enormous variation even in what an individual developer will do from one problem to the next - let alone the variation between individuals, and the variation in how teams are organised and how that changes over time.

A seriously overlooked area in the analysis of software development practice, is the "process" for reproducing software developers. It is not unusual for those engaged in some sort of software development have no specific training or education in it at all - neither moulded by the education system, nor the beneficiary of a long apprenticeship with experienced workers as is typical of other professions.

Even computer science, valuable as it is, does more to describe how the tools of the trade work in themselves, rather than how those tools ought to be effectively employed - in the same way that mechanics scarcely informs one how to drive a car to a legal standard.

So in my view, software development simply does not consist of well-defined processes. Small localised areas of common habit are observable, the experienced practitioner may feel that he is highly systematic, and teams may work together satisfactorily.

But the same goes for a band of musicians, and yet the process of penning hit music (in fact, any music) always defies a standard description of what the requirements of a hit are, and how the words and the notes were assembled to meet those requirements.